# Проблема со ссылками после переноса сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Перенес сайт на WordPress на другой хостинг и домен, возникла проблема со ссылками (при клике на любую кнопку главной страницы сайта она отправляет по адресу прошлого домена).

Начал гуглить - нагуглил, что нужно зайти в админ панель и в настройках поменять тип ссылок на любой другой, казалось бы все просто.

Но трабл в том, что при вбивании в адресную строку "*[http://мойновыйдомен.ru/wp-admin](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.ru/wp-admin)*", он опять меняет введённый домен на предыдущий и выводит мне Форму входа на сайт, который расположен на предыдущем домене (другими словами, отправляет меня по адресу "*[http://мойстарыйдомен.ru/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fe90464cs.beget.tech%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.ru/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fe90464cs.beget.tech%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1)*"), то есть попасть в админ панель я тоже не могу, т.к. он опять же подменяет ссылку (

Как эта проблема решается?

Comment: Проблема решается правильным переносом сайта на WP: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Проблему как всегда решил KAGG Design: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/Как-правильно-перенести-сайт-на-wordpress/767562#767562    спасибо!!!!!!!

Comment: можете поставить там плюсики, на вопрос и на ответ)